# C++ Thread and Promise : attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I have some trouble running this example I found online.

```
void asyncFun(std::promise<int> intPromise) {
    int result=5;
    try {
        // calculate the result
        intPromise.set_value(result);
    }
    catch (...) {
        intPromise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    } 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    std::promise<int> intPromise;
    std::future<int> intFuture = intPromise.get_future();
    std::thread t(asyncFun, std::move(intPromise));
    std::cout << "Main thread" << std::endl;
    int result = intFuture.get(); // may throw MyException
    std::cout << result<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And i'm getting :

> error C2280: 'std::promise::promise(const
>   std::promise &)' : attempting to reference a deleted
>   function  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\functional    1149    1   tryFuture

Comment: It's a bug, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: using VS 2013, i'm installing now 2015

Comment: Ok, but there is another workaround as well, using `shared_ptr`, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the implementation you are using. Consider upgrading if you can.

The arguments to `std::thread` are required to be [*MoveConstructible*](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#3), `std::promise` satisfies these requirements.

It compiles online at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net and runs (with the added `t.join()` in `main`). As a work-around, you could consider "feeding" a reference (with `std::ref`  and moving from the `promise`), but be warning of dangling references with such a workaround.

Another workaround here is to use a `std::shared_ptr` with the `std::promise` as an argument to the function.

```
void asyncFun(std::shared_ptr<std::promise<int>> intPromise) {
    int result=5;
    try {
        // calculate the result
        intPromise->set_value(result);
    }
    catch (...) {
        intPromise->set_exception(std::current_exception());
    } 
}

int main() {
    std::promise<int> intPromise;
    std::future<int> intFuture = intPromise.get_future();
    auto sh = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>(std::move(intPromise));
    std::thread t(asyncFun, sh);
    std::cout << "Main thread" << std::endl;
    int result = intFuture.get(); // may throw MyException
    std::cout << result<<std::endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're right, the code i've posted above is an example,my code have a loop so i can't use refernce otherwise i'll lose them when i'll go out from loop

Comment: No problem, the `shared_ptr` alternative will help with that.